# Programação em C usando GTK

Tags: c, gtk

Tenho que fazer um jogo como trabalho na faculdade (Scrabble).

O problema é o seguinte. Quando o `event_box` do atril do jogador é pressionado chamo uma função callback, para que a imagem que está no `event_box` pressionado seja removida e logo em seguida adiciona outra imagem. Mas a nova imagem não é adicionada. E quando executo e clico no `event_box`, a imagem é simplesmente eliminada.

Uso a função `gtk_container_remove` para remover a imagem e `gtk_container_add` para adicionar a nova imagem (coisa que não acontece).

Lembrando que comecei a usar GTK há uma semana.

```
void selecFichas(GtkWidget *casillaAtril, gpointer data){
    int i;

    image = gtk_image_new_from_file("casilla.png");
    g_object_ref(image);

    estado = 1;
    for(i = 0; i < LETRAS; i++)
        if(casillaAtril == atrilJogador1[i]){
            Element = i; // determina cual event_box(casilla del atril) fue presionado
            break;
        }
    gtk_container_remove(GTK_CONTAINER[atrilJugador1[Element]), fichasABC[coordImagen[Element][0]][coodImagen[Element][1]]);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER[atrilJugador1[Element]), image);
}
```

Comment: Boa noite Ana, poste o código, imagens de códigos são mais dificeis de reproduzir, se algo pode ser texto então use texto, realmente é complicado tirar uma foto do código né? Espero que entenda isto como uma critica positiva.

Comment: Imagens do código também são invisíveis para mecanismos de busca, então outras pessoas podem não encontrar a solução para o problema similar delas.

Comment: Ana Cris, você fala português? *¿Ana Cris, usted hablas portugués?* Pergunto isso porque o seu código está em espanhol e você usou as palavras "add" e "atril" no texto.

Comment: Falo os dois idiomas :)

Comment: @AnaCris , o trabalho da faculdade exige que vc use GTK ou vc escolheu usar GTK ?

Comment: @AnaCris Gostaria de saber se você já solucionou seu problema - acredito que já. Se sim, coloque uma resposta você mesma e marque-a como solução!

Se você não solucionou o problema, poderia me dizer se aquela variável `image` é do tipo `GtkWidget *`? Também gostaria de dizer o seguinte: eu particularmente não gosto do uso de variáveis globais não constantes como `image`, `estado`, `Element` e as outras presentes na sua função. Eu recomendo - acredito que muitos outros também - que você referencie tudo na função que for usar e só então modificar seus conteúdos.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1763068/6998967) não é necessário criar um novo Widget para trocar a imagem. Basta usar [gtk_image_set_from_image()](http://developer.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkImage.html#gtk-image-set-from-image) *__deprecated__* (ou talvez [gtk_image_set_from_file()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkImage.html#gtk-image-set-from-file) )
Extraí o código abaixo desta [outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14367406/6998967) e imagino que ele resolva seu problema. O exemplo que segue é de um *array* de imagens que representam "leds"; se você clicar em uma imagem, por exemplo, o led acenderá/apagará com uma mudança da imagem do widget *img* da struct *led* (veja a callback `click_handler()`). O código é bem fácil de entender, aproveite :-)

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#define ICON_WIDTH 16
#define ICON_HEIGHT 16
#define NUM_LEDS 2500

typedef enum {
    ON,
    OFF
} led_status;

typedef struct {
    GtkWidget *img;
    struct {
        gint x;
        gint y;
    } pos;
    led_status status;
} led;

static led leds[NUM_LEDS];
static GdkPixbuf *led_on;
static GdkPixbuf *led_off;

static gboolean click_handler(GtkWidget *widget,
                              GdkEvent *event,
                              gpointer user_data)
{
    led *info = user_data;

    if (info->status == ON) {
        gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(info->img), led_off);
        info->status = OFF;
    } else {
        gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(info->img), led_on);
        info->status = ON;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    GtkWidget *window, *layout;
    int i = 0, x, y;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    /* Load our images (ignoring errors - as any good sample code would) */
    led_on  = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("led-on.png", NULL);
    led_off = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file("led-off.png", NULL);

    /* Initialize our array */
    for (x = 0; x < 50; x++) {
        for (y = 0; y < 50; y++) {
            leds[i].img = gtk_image_new();
            leds[i].pos.x = x * ICON_WIDTH;
            leds[i].pos.y = y * ICON_HEIGHT;
            leds[i].status = OFF;

            /* Initialize our image from the pixbuf we've already loaded */
            gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(leds[i].img), led_off);
            i++;
        }
    }

    /* Create a window */
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "LEDs");
    gtk_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT(window),
                       "destroy",
                       G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),
                       NULL);

    /* Create the widget */
    layout = gtk_layout_new(NULL, NULL);

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
        /*
         * A GtkImage doesn't have a window, so we need to put it inside
         * a GtkEventBox so we can capture events.
         */
        GtkWidget *eb = gtk_event_box_new();
        g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(eb),
                         "button_press_event",
                         G_CALLBACK(click_handler),
                         &leds[i]);
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(eb), leds[i].img);
        gtk_layout_put(GTK_LAYOUT(layout), eb, leds[i].pos.x, leds[i].pos.y);
    }

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), layout);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```